# Saving form data in mvc3 having multiple div in forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a user profile page,

in that i have many section.

like User Information,

Education Information,

Work Information and many more...

I have created model for Profilesection that is main model. (ProfileModel).
like wise i have model for user information, education information and so on...

I have a save and cancel button for each section.
How can i save from details in to my database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to think about the model you are creating and how you are processing that model. You may have already looked it but I think looking at How asp net handle related data may help you here.
I have provided a link [here](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) that will hopefully help you if not then feel free not to select my answer.